# Speed up animation of TitlePane in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to speed up or remove the wipeIn and wipeOut animation of a title pane in Dojo. The content should appear immediately after clicking on the title bar. In other frameworks, I would modify the animation speed or duration but I had no luck with this in dojo so far. I've also tried to overwrite the animation without too much success.

This is (simplified) how I create the TitlePane:

```
require(["dijit/TitlePane", "dojo/dom-construct"], function(TitlePane, domConstruct){
    var titlePaneOptions = {};
    titlePaneOptions.title = "Some Title";
    titlePaneOptions.open = true;
    titlePaneOptions.content = "Content";

    this._titlePane = new TitlePane(titlePaneOptions);
    domConstruct.place(this._titlePane.domNode, this.context.element, "only");

    this._titlePane.startup();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the API docs for [TitlePane](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.10/dijit/TitlePane.html), under Property Summary, there is a `duration`:

> duration - Time in milliseconds to fade in/fade out

So for example:

```
var titlePaneOptions = {};
titlePaneOptions.title = "Some Title";
titlePaneOptions.open = true;
titlePaneOptions.content = "Content";
titlePaneOptions.duration = 0;
```

.. should make it appear/disappear immediately.